# Wordpress: has_shortcode() - how to detect nested shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using `has_shortcode()` to detect a shortcode, it works but not at all. If I put this specified shortcode inside another one the `has_shortcode()` function stops working.

```
has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'slider' )
```

For example:

```
[2col] //left column
[slider]
[2col_next] //right column
[slider]
[/2col]
```

The `has_shortcode()` function won't work in that case but if I use `[slider]` shortcode without `[2col]` it works perfect. This refers to every shortcode. I'm pretty sure that there's nothing wrong with my shortcodes.

Answer (score 2):

Was looking for a solution to this just now. If anyone else is still looking for it then it has been answered here:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126563/has-shortcode-how-to-detect-nested-shortcode

Reworked translation of above link in case it becomes broken:

```
    function is_shortcode_active() {
        global $post;

        if ( strpos( $post->post_content, '[shortcode' ) ) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I changed it a bit from the original linked answer. I just used the `$post` object instead of other functions and I also removed the `/` after the opening bracket and left off the closing bracket completely. The reason for leaving off the ending bracket is in case you are tyring to find a shortcode in which users may have added attributes to - if the `]` is there then it won't match in those instances.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Ah ok. Still new to this whole network of sites, but that does make sense. I will go ahead and edit my answer to include more information.

Comment: that would be really great.